# Blender Solidify for rc plane wing

Tags: mesh

I am trying to print a wing for a rc plane with my 3D printer. In order to make the wing as light as possible I need to hollow it (put some stable structure there). I've tried the Blender Solidify modifier to do this but without success. The material on the sharp edge on the rear part of the wing gets thinner and thinner although the "Even Thickness" option is checked (see picture). When preparing this for printing, the slicer puts only one line of filament there instead of two. What I need is a brim on the inner side of the stl file with a constant spacing.

[image: rc plane wing]

Can someone please help me? I would appreciate any suggestion or other programs which can handle this problem. I've already tried Meshmixer which also has problems with this sharp edge :-(

My Blender Solidify setup:
Thickness: 1.0
Offset: -1.0
Clamp: 2.0
Even Thickness: checked
High Quality: checked
Fill Rim: checked

The stl file of the wing can be found here: https://files.fm/u/5futezwj

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The acute angle in the trailing edge of the wing will result in the even thicknesses overlapping, I think the surest solution is a bit of remodeling.

- Detach the faces constituting the outside of the trailing edge, <kbd>P</kbd> separate to a new object
- Delete the appropriate inner faces of the rest of the wing, and fill the hole, to prepare to solidify the rest of the wing independently of the trailing edge
- Solidify and apply the modifier
- Recreate the hole for the trailing edge
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>Rejoin the trailing  edge and the wing, Remove Doubles, tidy up.

[image]

This example treatment of your wing passes basic Manifold checks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a more automated solution as I have to hollow even more complex objects? Even another program would be fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of one... you would have thought there _must_  be something out there somewhere, the amount of injection molding etc. there is in the world... I would be looking more in the area of CAD/CAM applications?

Comment: @fuxT    A quick look suggests [Meshmixer's Hollow tool](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MSHMXR/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-4092B330-FF8D-4523-BB43-9453F60BCF4E), which is voxel-based?